# Problems importing new Image Target

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, augmented-reality, importerror, vuforia

I have been importing my 65 or so image targets a few at a time into Unity via the Vuforia plugin with no problems whatsoever for the last couple of months, but when I try to import 2 new image targets using the usual procedure, i get a warning on the console "Overriding existing asset with new GUID from package, this may break links within your project to package assets"

Then for some strange reason, the new image target will not show up on the list of image targets to select from in the inspector (under component "Image Target Behaviour (Script) > Image Target"). All my previous image targets work fine and show up on that list.

Have tried several different ways of importing all targets again, or the 1 new one alone, with or without the .dat or .xml files, restarting, rebooting etc, all to no avail. It's impossible to make it show the new image targets into my inspector so I cannot use them (despite that they still show up in Assets as imageTarget_scaled.jpg).

I am running the latest Unity (5.6.1f1 Personal(64bit)) and the Vuforia SDK v6.2.10.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload images anytime in the vuforia target manager. Just remember to download the database again and reimport it in your project so Unity can detect the changes